# How to pass array in Custom validation in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have pass an array`booking_type_all` parameter in custom validation.
It's giving the error:

> Array to string conversion

How to pass the array?

```
$validatedData = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'couponcode' => 'validcoupon:$request->booking_type_all,
    ]);
```

Array `booking_type_all`:

```
array:1 [
  "TOURS" => array:1 [
    0 => "99848892-8617-41b9-808c-c44ca529d4e1"
  ],
  "VEHICLE" => array:1 [
    0 => "99848892-8617-41b9-808c-c44ca529d4e2"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you are understanding the concept of "Custom Validation" here. I would suggest you go through the [documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-validation-rules) to understand it thoroughly.

In short, when you create a custom validation rule, preferably "Using Rule Objects", your rule will start working exactly the same as inbuild validation rules required, nullable, etc. work.

So you provide the whole `request` for validation and as a key, the name of variable you want to validate and as value, the rules you want to validate on that variable.

You do not need to provide particular array for particular custom validation.

So you will do something like this:

```
$validatedData = Validator::make($request->all(),[
    'booking_type_all' => 'validcoupon',
]);
```

where `validcoupon` is a custom rule to validate the array `booking_type_all` which is present in request payload.

Or

If you want to validate the keys present inside `booking_type_all` array only and it contains some key like `couponcode` for which you have created your custom validation then you can do it like this:

```
$validatedData = Validator::make($request->booking_type_all,[
    'couponcode' => 'validcoupon',
]);
```

In this scenario, you dont care about full request payload as you are only concerned with `booking_type_all` array in it.